# Where is this round blue BIONICLE figure from with circular hands and a transparent head?

Tags: set-identification, bionicle

[image]

Please help me identify this blue BIONICLE figure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [donutsftw's answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/7468/6584) is what you're looking for. You should accept that answer when you have a chance. :)

Comment: Where's tje picture?

Answer (score 6):

The set in question is [8562 Gahlok](http://brickset.com/sets/8562-1/Gahlok). It's missing the legs and parts of its head.

Comment: The cover also appears upside down.

Answer (score 1):

Every LEGO brick has an ID printed somewhere on it. Grab the ID from any piece and then head over to http://brickset.com, then do a search (top right) and select "parts" from the dropdown list. This will show you all the sets that part is used in and you can go from there.